# React - an reponse data array is cleared after assigning it to state in a useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, request, use-effect

I use MongoDB to store data. The database works properly, as it can be tested in a when an endpoint is access. I use the `useEffect` hook to fetch data from the database. The code is as follows:

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    personService.getAll().then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setPersons(response.data);
      console.log(persons);
    });
  }, []);
```

The first `console.log()` logs the result as expected, an array of JavaScript objects is returned. However, after assigning it to `persons` state using `setPersons` method, the state remains empty and nothing is rendered. What could be the problem here and how to make data appear on the page?

EDIT: I solved the problem it was because MongoDB returns fields as objects, even though they appear to be strings. I had to redefine the `toJSON` method using mongoose.

Comment: Try to log persons array right below it's definition code. in the next render circle (after useEffect callback ran), it will log the persons list.

Answer (score 0):

Because state only has value when component rerender. So you should put `console.log` into useEffect to check when component re-render success.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(persons);
  }, [persons]);
```

Comment: When I do this, the requests are sent infinitely.

Comment: This is the other `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState as well.

So when you call setPersons(response.data), this action may not be even be completed, and you are logging persons.

If you log the persons outside the useEffect you should be able to see it, as component would rerender as soon as the state is updated, logging "persons".

Comment: Yes, I logged it in JSX and it is updated, but how can I fetch the data in an other way? The `useEffect()` hook is supposed to br used for actions like fetching the data from API.

Comment: Can you explain your problem again? Didnt get the above comment.